# VBA Create a list of files from a FTP server

Tags: excel, ftp, vba

Looking for VBA code to create a list of files on a FTP server.  Ideally it would be great to include the file attributes such as date/time file was created.

Answer (score 4):

I create class named `FileInformation` and a function getFileList that will return an array of FileInformation.  `GetFTPFileList` allows you to use `getFileList` with a ftp server.

[image]

**Class FileInformation**

```
    Option Explicit

    Public FilePath
    Public FolderPath
    Public FileExtension

    Public Sub setValues(localRoot, fso, f)
        FilePath = f.Path
        FolderPath = f.ParentFolder.Path
        FileExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(FilePath)
    End Sub
```

The rest of the code goes into a normal code module.

```
    Sub PrintFileInformation()
        Const Username As String = ""
        Const Password As String = ""
        Const ftpSite As String = ""
        Const ftpRoot As String = ""
        Dim arFiles
        Dim i As Long

        arFiles = getFTPFileList(Username, Password, ftpSite, ftpRoot)

        For i = 0 To UBound(arFiles)
            Debug.Print arFiles(i).FilePath
            Debug.Print arFiles(i).FolderPath
            Debug.Print arFiles(i).FileExtension
        Next

    End Sub

    Function getFTPFileList(Username As String, Password As String, ftpSite As String, ftpRoot As String)

        ftpRoot = "ftp://" & Username & ":" & Password & "@" & ftpSite & "/" & ftpRoot
        getFTPFileList = getFileList(ftpRoot)

    End Function

    Function getFileList(localRoot As String, Optional fld, Optional ftpArray)
        Dim fso, f, baseFolder, subFolder, ftpFile, i

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

        If IsMissing(fld) Then
            Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot)
        Else
            Set baseFolder = fld
        End If

        For Each f In baseFolder.Files

            If IsMissing(ftpArray) Then
                ReDim ftpArray(0)
            Else
                i = UBound(ftpArray) + 1
                ReDim Preserve ftpArray(i)
            End If
            Set ftpFile = New FileInformation
            ftpFile.setValues localRoot, fso, f
            Set ftpArray(i) = ftpFile

        Next

        For Each subFolder In baseFolder.SubFolders
            getFileList localRoot, subFolder, ftpArray
        Next

        getFileList = ftpArray
    End Function
```

Comment: I am getting path not found error when i reach the line Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot).
My ftpRoot variable is having data as ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp://fts.factset.com/datafeeds/fundamentals/ff_advanced_am_v3//ftp://fts.factset.com/